# HTML div bg color out of screen

Tags: css, html, background, styles

I want to create a `<div>` element with background color, which starts in the middle of the screen and goes to the right, to the end of the page (out of screen) , but I don´t want to trigger any scroll bar. In that `<div>` I want to have some information, at the beginning of that `<div>`(within the screen). 
Here´s the HTML code example:

```
<div id="footer">
   <h2>Information</h2>
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p class="alignright">Another information in this paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look like:

http://postimage.org/image/h60apjfjf/

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382576/positioning-a-button-with-css/8382682#8382682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS will let you do this easily.  Something like the following:

```
#footer {
   background-color: #b0c4de;
   width: 50%;
   height: 20px;
   float: right;
}
```

This is a pretty good resource: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: It´s good, but what to do if I want width: 80%; ? It can´t be done like this because if you zoom this page, composition wouldn´t be the same.

Comment: Putting one div inside of another should theoretically maintain whatever ratio you set using the width property if done as a percentage.  I don't think there's a standard way of handling zoom behavior across browsers, but this should work.

Comment: Yes, but I want this div to start below another content. On my screen it would look fine (with width: 80%), but on some bigger screen it wouldn´t be positioned right below that content.

Answer (score 0):

Can´t you just use css background-image of the body to achieve that effect?

Comment: I have already defined one background-image of the body, and this footer would be changing its position according to the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
#footer {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

The overflow hidden isn't necessary but in case a scrollbar appears, with this it won't.

**EDIT:** example: http://jsfiddle.net/8nu68/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by wrapping the footer div in another div. This will not only allow you to fully position the footer div but it will also allow you to put the footer div outside without generating a scrollbar or showing the overflow.

For example:

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">

    <div id="footer">

        <h2>Information</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p class="alignright">Another information in this paragraph.</p>

    </div>

</div>

#footer-wrapper { width:300px; height:100px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
#footer { position:absolute: top:50px; left:50%; width:300px; }
```

etc.

The position:relative means that the footer div, with position:absolute, will use the wrapper as the position reference. Overflow:hidden will prevent scroll bars and will hide the overflow.